# parse span element InnerText to a javascript key value object

Tags: javascript, dom, reduce, key-value, selectors-api

I have the following div element and i would like to parse the span text save it as key value pair.

```html
<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">ADDITIONAL_WRK</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill">DECIMAL</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a"> AFFECTMRAPPLIC</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill"> DECIMAL</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">APPROVED_ON</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill">TIMESTAMP</span >
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">COMPOSITE</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am able to get them individually using the following:

```js
// first span
var firstSpan= document.getElementsByClassName( 'data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a' )
var firstSpanArray = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < firstSpan.length; ++i ) {
    firstSpanArray.push( firstSpan[i].innerText );
}

// var second span
var secondSpan= document.getElementsByClassName( 'sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill' )
var secondSpanArray = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < secondSpan.length; ++i ) {
    secondSpanArray.push( secondSpan[i].innerText);
}
```

Now i want to combine `firstSpanArray` and `secondSpanArray` using the index into a key value javascript object,but the issue is for some the second span is not there and so the index is not a one to one match.
can any help me expand this query so that i get something like this :

```js
spanCollection = {
  "ADDITIONAL_WRK":"DECIMAL",
  "AFFECTMRAPPLIC":"DECIMAL", 
  "APPROVED_ON":"TIMESTAMP",
  "COMPOSITE":""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by selecting the second div in the first loop by "asking" the parent if it has one. And if not (result 'null') set the value to an empty string.

**Working example:**

```js
var firstSpan = document.getElementsByClassName('data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a');
var spanCollection = {};

for (var i = 0; i < firstSpan.length; ++i) {
  var value_span = firstSpan[i].parentNode.querySelector('.sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis.sp3-fill');
  var span_value = value_span ? value_span.innerText : '';
  var span_key = firstSpan[i].innerText;
  spanCollection[span_key] = span_value;
}

console.log(spanCollection);
```

```html
<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">ADDITIONAL_WRK</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill">DECIMAL</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a"> AFFECTMRAPPLIC</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill"> DECIMAL</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">APPROVED_ON</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill">TIMESTAMP</span >
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">COMPOSITE</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The task can be easily achieved in many ways.

One was to choose a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach, where one does iterate an array of nodes derived from [a queried `NodeList` where each node classifies as `.data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), hence the nodes where each node contains the key-name.

With each iteration step one would ...

- extract the key-name from the currently processed key-containing node.

  ```
  const key = keyNode.textContent.trim();
  ```
- query the corresponding/related, value-containing, node of each currently processed key-containing node. If the related value-data exists, one does extract it. The fallback for non-existing value-data is always the empty string. For the latter extraction one would use a combination of [`Element::querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and the [*optional chaining operator / `?.`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

  ```
  const value = keyNode.parentNode.querySelector('.sp3-fill')?.textContent.trim() || '';
  ```

During the entire `reduce` cycle one, via [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), does aggregate the empty object which was passed as [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value). The reducer function's return value is this, initially empty, object of aggregated key-value pairs ...

```js
const spanCollection = [
  ...document.querySelectorAll('.data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a')
]
.reduce((result, keyNode) => {

  const key = keyNode
    .textContent.trim();
  const value = keyNode
    .parentNode.querySelector('.sp3-fill')?.textContent.trim() || '';

  return Object.assign(result, { [ key ]: value });

}, {});

console.log({ spanCollection });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">ADDITIONAL_WRK</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill">DECIMAL</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a"> AFFECTMRAPPLIC</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill"> DECIMAL</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">APPROVED_ON</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill">TIMESTAMP</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">COMPOSITE</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A second approach could be build on `reduce` as well, but this time
the to be reduced data is an array of nodes, where each node's text content contains the entire key-value data, a string, after being [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)med, of following form ...

```
'a_one_word_key     and a lot of value data'
```

The above example value, split via a regex like ...

```
'a_one_word_key     and a lot of value data'.split(/(\s+)/);
```

... which preserves the whitespace-sequences at which the splitting happens, results in following array ...

```
['a_one_word_key', '     ', 'and', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'lot', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'value', ' ', 'data']
```

It is clear that one, via [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring), can access the needed key-value data like this ...

```
const [key, _, ...valueData] = keyValueNode.textContent.trim().split(/(\s+)/);
```

`key` is always present, the underscore represents the optional (and anyhow not needed) first split whitespace sequence. And `valueData`, which gets accessed via the [rest property syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property), is optional as well, but will always default to an empty array. Thus, regardless of the source-data, one always deals with defined key-value data.

The object aggregation of the first provided `reduce` example then changes slightly to ...

```
Object.assign(result, { [ key ]: valueData.join('') });
```

And the 2nd solution's example code in its entirety looks like follows ...

```js
const spanCollection = [
  ...document.querySelectorAll('.data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a')
]
.reduce((result, keyValueNode) => {

  const [key, _, ...valueData] = keyValueNode.textContent.trim().split(/(\s+)/);

  return Object.assign(result, { [ key ]: valueData.join('') });

}, {});

console.log({ spanCollection });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">ADDITIONAL_WRK</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill">DECIMAL</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a"> AFFECTMRAPPLIC</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill"> DECIMAL</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">APPROVED_ON</span>

      <span class="sp3-tag sp3-intent-danger">
        <span class="sp3-text-overflow-ellipsis sp3-fill">TIMESTAMP</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-diff-span__composite-list-item__18c5zip data-diff-core__highlight-area__19c0zip">
  <div class="data-diff-basic__class-row__4ngp30a">
    <div class="data-diff-basic__class-header__4ngp30a">
      <span class="data-diff-basic__class-name__4ngp30a">COMPOSITE</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```